# Opening an App from a WebPage

Tags: html, ios, hyperlink, url-scheme

I am developing a web app which I need to open a particular app. I have found this site: http://handleopenurl.com/ which gives some of the app url. But there isn't the app that I want, which is PolyCom RealPresence.

How can I get any app url which is not in that site.

I have tried the following:

```
<a href="tel:99845075">99845075</a> <!-- Works -->
<a href="sms:99845075">New SMS Message</a> <!-- Works -->
<a href="itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pages/id361309726?mt=8&uo=4">ITunes</a> <!-- Works -->
<a href="realpresence://callTo">PolycOM</a> <!-- Do not Work -->
```

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Pheraps do you need something like this?
http://itunes.apple.com/it/linkmaker/

Comment: But that is a link to the App store. What I want is a link to the app itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a Polycom rep says the only way to call in the app is IP dialing only (basic mode), or with alias or IP based (pro mode) - custom URL scheme to open the app and direct a specific call is **not** supported as of June 2013

see Polycom rep answer identical question here on their forums - http://community.polycom.com/t5/RealPresence-Mobile/Is-it-possible-for-the-RealPresence-Mobile-iOS-to-dial-URL/td-p/13480

Comment: Thanks. Just saw the post. It's a shame, as this is a good app and is limited by this small thing.

Answer (score 1):

Check out *Implementing Custom URL Schemes* in [iOS App Programming Guide: Advanced App Tricks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50).

If the third party app in question implements a custom URL scheme, you need to figure out what it is and use that.  Otherwise, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: The problem is that this is not my app. Is a third party app which will be called from my web page.

Comment: Is there a way to use callto function?

Comment: If you are looking to make a phone call but that doesn't sound like what you are doing...